# Passing a variable through to .done(function()

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function, post

Ok, so I have the following function:

```
function add_like(post_id) {
    $.post('php/like_add.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data){
        if (data == 'success') {
            bump_get(photo_id).done(function(){
                toggle_visibility('bump_img'+post_id);
            });
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Currently this runs, and `php/like_add.php` echo's `success` correctly. The issue is that for the main post function I pass the post_id to it, but for the `.done(function()`; the post_id is not passed to it. So the id for `toggle_visibility` is becoming 'like_post_' instead of 'like_post_x'. How do I pass a variable to a .done function from the function running immediately before it?

I tried `bump_get(photo_id).done({photo_id:photo_id}, function(){`, but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: As it stands, the `post_id` passed to `toggle_visibility` will be **exactly** the same value sent to `like_add.php`. You need to come up with a http://sscce.org/ on http://jsfiddle.net to properly demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Your description does not match your code. There's nowhere that echoes or alerts 'success', and there's nothing that references anything like `like_post`.

Comment: @jcsanyi I explained what produced 'success' in my question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the variable with an immediately called anonymous function:

```
function add_like(post_id) {
    $.post('php/like_add.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data){
        if (data == 'success') {
            bump_get(photo_id).done((function(post_id){
                return function(){
                    toggle_visibility('bump_img'+post_id);
                };
            })(post_id));
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way variable scope and closures in javascript work, the correct `post_id` value will already be available in your callback function.

When you call `add_like()`, a new scope is created, and the `post_id` variable is created in that scope because it's an argument of the function. Variables in that scope are available throughout the execution of the function, **as well as after the function ends** for any anonymous functions (closures) that were created - such as your callback.

As a proof-of-concept, see the following simplified code, which you can run in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R4HNx/

```
function add_like(post_id) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(post_id);
    }, 2000);
}
add_like(10);
```

This replaces the ajax callback with a simple `setTimeout()` call, but it's the same concept - we're defining a callback function that will run at some point in the future, and using a variable from the parent function which will have returned long before the callback actually runs.